# Katharsis security + API versioning

Tags: spring, rest, katharsis

I am currently evaluating possibilities, how to write/generate level2+ rest API. I came across karharis and i pretty like the concept and the whole idea how its done seems sound to me. But I have not found answers to these questions:

1. How to handle security properly. I can imagine that it might get tricky, as JSON api supports traversing to some extent. (out app will run in spring environment, so I suppose that we might use spring-security, but I do not know, if we will encounter some hidden traps)
2. API versioning. I havent found any clues how to handle API evolution. Are there any already supported options (content negotiation, path variable, query parameter...?) or do we need to hack it ourselves?

Thanks in advance!